# Excel consolidate same values on column1 while keeping data

Tags: excel

I have a excel table which looks like this one.

[image: Picture1]

As you can see, this products 2005 and 3004 are listed more than once because this same products have different price value based on sale scala. Like, if you buy 50 each of that item, the price gets lower.

What I want is -assuming there is a way to achieve- is this :

[image: Picture2]

ProductID Column is Unique and entrys with same product ID gathers on 1 row. With their Sale Scala and Price(Per) values added(if there is) within next columns. Is there a solution to alter the table like this with coding ? There is too much line to manually edit.

Please Suggest. Thanks.

Comment: If this is a one-time processing operation, your best bet is to save the data as a CSV file and process it with a script written in a language like Perl. Once that is done you can got back to Excel.

Comment: Yes I need this process just once, then I'll carry the new format to sql server. But unfortunately I don't know how to use Perl.

Comment: You could likely do the operation in most languages, I just gave Perl as an example because it is what I use for work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this but I've created a simple loop that looks for duplicate values in column A then processes the data accordingly.  I'm working bottom up for simplicity.  Note: You'll have to manually create your headers when finished unless you want to add more logic.

**EDIT** Simpler code

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

    Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With WS
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
    End With

    'Loop through column A bottom up
    For i = LastCellRowNumber To 2 Step -1
        ' Check if value in current cell matches value in cell above it
        If (Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
            'Shift current values over
            Range("C" & i & ":D" & i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

            'Copy new values down
            Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value
            Range("D" & i).Value = Range("D" & i - 1).Value

            'Delete row
            Rows(i - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]